# Pass a variable between functions within a class

Tags: python, class, oop, regression, linear-regression

How can I pass a variable returned by a function within a class to another function within that class?
For example (implementing linear regression):

```
class ForwardPropagation(object):
    def __init__(self, xs, realoutput): 
        self.xs = np.asarray(xs)
        self.realoutput = np.asarray(realoutput)
        self.guess_slope = random.randint(1,10)
        self.guess_b = random.randint(1,10)
        self.guess_output = (self.guess_slope * self.xs) + self.guess_b

    def distance(self):#returns np.array with distance results
        abs_D = self.realoutput - self.guess_output
        D_sqr = abs_D ** 2
        return abs_D, D_sqr

    def error(self):
        sigma = np.sum(D_sqr)
        mean_error = sigma / len(D_sqr)
        return mean_error
```

How can I pass the variable D_sqr, which is the squared of my distance function, to the error function?

Comment: There's an error in your distance function--it will never return D_sqr, as it will break at the first return statement. If you want to return both D_sqr and abs_D, you can return them as a tuple like so:
`return abs_D, D_sqr`

Comment: In the distance function you cannot have two returns, the second return will not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything when you can call the other function

```
def distance(self):#returns np.array with distance results
    abs_D = self.realoutput - self.guess_output
    D_sqr = abs_D ** 2
    return abs_D, D_sqr

def error(self):
    abs_D, D_sqr = self.distance()
    sigma = np.sum(D_sqr)
    mean_error = sigma / len(D_sqr)
    return mean_error
```

Or you could recalculate it again

```
def error(self):
    abs_D = self.realoutput - self.guess_output
    D_sqr = abs_D ** 2
    sigma = np.sum(D_sqr)
    mean_error = sigma / len(D_sqr)
    return mean_error
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class variables

```
 self.D_sqr = D_sqr
```

And in error:

```
sigma = np.sum(self.D_sqr)
```